# Why is the right translation of 不滅のあなたへ "to the immortal, you" and not "to your immortality"?

Tags: particle-の

When you are trying to learn japanese you see dozens of webpages stating that the no particle works for indicating possesion, for example, [possesion and position with no](https://m.japanesemeow.com/japanese-grammar-lessons/possession-and-position-with-no/)

However, the anime manga 不滅のあなたへ is translated literally as "to the immortal, you" (similar to an English vocative I guess), and not "to your immortality"? [To your eternity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Your_Eternity) (the article mentions the literal translation is "to you, the immortal", and not "to your eternity" which I suppose is an adapted translation. Also the Google translator translates it that way [fumetsu no anata e Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=translator&source=hp&ei=p9JCY_6UE8Xb1sQP3syW0Ag&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAY0Lgt_4802Dsk9zyfHPUWD2o5zM3kfKH&ved=0ahUKEwi-hMaWptP6AhXFrZUCHV6mBYoQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=translator&gs_lp=Egdnd3Mtd2l6uAED-AEBMgoQABjqAhi0AhhDMhEQABjqAhi0AhiKAxi3AxjlAjIREAAY6gIYtAIYigMYtwMY5QIyERAAGOoCGLQCGIoDGLcDGOUCMhEQABjqAhi0AhiKAxi3AxjlAjIREAAY6gIYtAIYigMYtwMY5QIyERAAGOoCGLQCGIoDGLcDGOUCMhEQABjqAhi0AhiKAxi3AxjlAjIREAAY6gIYtAIYigMYtwMY5QIyERAAGOoCGLQCGIoDGLcDGOUCwgIREC4YgAQYsQMYgwEYxwEY0QPCAgsQABiABBixAxiDAcICBRAAGIAEwgIIEC4YgAQYsQPCAg4QLhiABBixAxjHARjRA8ICChAAGLEDGIMBGEOoAgpIyDtQAFixOnAGeADIAQCQAQKYAdwJoAHBH6oBBTYtMi4y&sclient=gws-wiz) "to the immortal you".

"to the immortal you" or "to you, the immortal", isnt the same meaning at all than "to your immortality".

Why is the right translation of 不滅のあなたへ "to the immortal, you" and not "to your immortality", if one would apply the rule of no indicating possesion the resulting translation is "to your immortality"?

Comment: "Your X" would be あなたのX. Your sentence has Xのあなた.

Comment: @user3856370 ohh, it's inverted. Thanks, I didnt realize it.

Comment: Also, relative clauses modify pronouns *much* more frequently in Japanese

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the following usage of [の](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%AE/#je-58755).

> 5〔形状，性質〕
>
> 正方形の箱
> a square box
>
> 雨の日
> a rainy day
>
> 金のメダル
> a gold medal
>
> 木の机
> a wooden desk／a desk made of wood
>
> ブロンズの彫刻
> a bronze sculpture／a sculpture in bronze
>
> 白髪の老人
> an old man with white hair／a white-haired old man
>
> 夢の国
> a dreamland
>
> 英語の演説
> 「an address [a speech] in English

Adding another example, コロナの人 would mean *a person infected with Covid*. In the same way, 不滅のあなた means *immortal you*.